# how to append a new container to a running task in AWS ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ecs

I'm using AWS ECS to start containers to run automated tests and their number cannot be known beforehand, because they are triggered by different events.

For some config reasons I have to start these tasks in `EC2` mode only (not `FARGATE`),

The issue is: I need to add new containers to a running task, but I couldn't achieve that, the only way I found is to start a new task for each new container, but this solution is very expensive in some cases.

I'm using `boto3` to start the new tasks&containers, I share with you this part of code to do that:

```
client = boto3.client('ecs', region_name="eu-west-1")

networkConfiguration = {
            'awsvpcConfiguration': {
                'subnets': ['subnet-01', 'subnet-06'],
            }
        }

resp = client.run_task(
        cluster='run-on-demand',
        launchType='EC2',
        taskDefinition="task-01-ec2",
        networkConfiguration=networkConfiguration,
        overrides={
            'containerOverrides': [
                {
                    'name': "task-01-c1-ec2",
                    'environment': env_vars,
                    'cpu': 512,
                    'memory': 2048
                }
            ],
        },
        startedBy="admin",
        count=1
    )
```

so my question is: is there any way to add new container to a running task ?

Comment: I am not aware of how boto's ecs library, but you can update a task definition with terraform and then the ecs agent will pick up the newly changed task and run it

Comment: @DimitrisMoraitidis: I have to keep the existant task running to not loose the execution results, that's why I want to update a RUNNING task and not updating a previous one

Comment: afaik, there is no way to do that. You either update an existing task definition (which will stop any running task with the previous definition), or create a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short answer: **it is not possible**, because the containers are defined at task creation time only.